# How to create a pdf viewer in html?

Tags: pdf, viewer

I just need a page to view pdf files in a Firefox browser. The files will be in any folder at my choosing. Kinda like what Firefox already does (like the picture attached), but a like to do this: when a select the file, the pdf pages are show to the right side. Sorry if it's too much to ask, but I couldn't find anything online, and I'm just starting to code, and I don't know how to do it...

I tried to do it with the code below... It didn't work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

   <html lang="pt-br">

   <head>

       <meta charset="UTF-8">

       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

       <title>Visualizador PDF</title>

       <style>

           css

   body, html {

       height: 100%;

       margin: 0;

       font-family: Arial, sans-serif;

   }

   .container {

       display: flex;

       height: 100%;

   }

   .lista {

       width: 30%;

       overflow-y: auto;

       border-right: 1px solid #ccc;

       padding: 10px;

   }

   .visualizador {

       width: 70%;

       padding: 10px;

   }

       </style>

   </head>

   <body>

       ok

       <div class="container">

       <div class="lista">

           <ul id="listaArquivos">

               

               <script>javascript

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    const listaArquivos = document.getElementById('listaArquivos');

    const pdfViewer = document.getElementById('pdfViewer');

    // Ajuste o caminho para a pasta pdfs localizada na sua área de trabalho

    const diretorio = "file:///C:/Users/F170593/Desktop/pdfs/"; // Atualize com seu nome de usuário

    fetch(diretorio).then(response => response.text()).then(text => {

        const parser = new DOMParser();

        const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");

        const items = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('a');  // Use querySelectorAll para obter todos os links

        items.forEach(item => {

            const nomeArquivo = item.textContent;

            if (nomeArquivo.endsWith('.pdf')) {

                const li = document.createElement('li');

                li.textContent = nomeArquivo;

                li.addEventListener('click', function() {

                    pdfViewer.src = diretorio + nomeArquivo;

                });

                listaArquivos.appendChild(li);

            }

        });

    });

});

</script>

           </ul>

       </div>

       <div class="visualizador">

           <iframe id="pdfViewer" width="100%" height="100%" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>

       </div>

   </div>

   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: It's for personal access usage, with the files in my pc. I have to read a bunch of pdf files everyday and this would help me...

Comment: Thanks man, but i have to say that I can't do what you suggested (i'm not sure if i even understand)... What i'm looking is something like the preview panel on windows 11. You just click on a file and it is shown to the right.... Is it possible to create something that does that?

Comment: I could use Edge if a had to...

Answer (score 0):

When accessing files in Windows, then MS Edge has a system access  advantage over other browsers as you can split the screen and open system folders in one half and use the other for viewing files such as ePub or PDF.

Here I am viewing #47 and you can see I am in the middle dragging 48.pdf to view that next.

[image]

You can start the process in a given folder from a shortcut
`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" %userprofile%/documents`
or simpler drag the starting folder into MS Edge

[image]

Multiple tabs or multiple Dual Windows no problem.
[image]

Comment: I guess the version of my browser doesn't have this feature, i couldn't find it (Version 108.0.1462.54). And I can't change that (it's a corporate PC) But it is ok... Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use newer MS Edge (version 111 or above) there  is almost a similar functionality in Firefox (Here I am using a Portable Copy). It requires Mozillas own extender (side-view) Where you can add folders and there add favourite files by drag and drop, it may be possible to bulk generate a loadable set of bookmarks too.

[image]